Specific issue to pandas comparing df with .where & .mask
I need to validate exported data against a configuration file with intended changes. i need to validate on a multi index of the first two columns. i need to return a dataframe with the same shape and values as the config but showing match for values that matched between the dataframe and the config or if it doesnt match then i would like for it to display 'config: {config value} | Export: {export value}' however i am having trouble pulling the non matched data from both frames thee way i want.
the files i need to go through are large and iterrows and apply are still fairly slow for what i want. i got close with df.mask() and df.where(). is there a way with the 'other' param to pull both of the values in the non matched cells from either df.mask or df.where? i am having trouble pulling just the piece of data relative to the cell. also i would prefer to not explicitly call out names of columns as i would like to use this for mult validation where the column names may differ. i have tried merges and joins also but i want the data to return this way specifically
import pandas as pd

# This will act as the config file for test casses, the other files can be considered as export files to match on the config

dfc = pd.DataFrame({'area id': ['8150', '8260', '8363', '8448'],
                   'code': ['Rc1', 'Rc1', 'Rc1', 'Rc1'],
                   'desc': ['RANDOM CODE', 'RANDOM CODE', 'RANDOM CODE', 'RANDOM CODE'],
                   'start date': ['123189', '123189', '123189', '123189']
                   })

# dF2 has 1 additional record for '8347' this should not show up on the results data

df2 = pd.DataFrame({'area id': ['8150', '8260', '8363', '8448', '8347'],
                   'code': ['Rc1', 'Rc1', 'Rc1', 'Rc1',  'Rc1'],
                   'desc': ['RANDOM CODE', 'RANDOM CODE', 'RANDOM CODE', 'RANDOM CODE', 'RANDOM CODE'],
                   'start date': ['123189', '123189', '123189', '123189',  '123189']
                   })

# df3 has 1 additional record for '8347' this should not show up on the results data
# For 'area id' record 8150 & 8260, 'desc' column value == RANDOM CODE1 this should return a non matched result

df3 = pd.DataFrame({'area id': ['8150', '8260', '8363', '8448', '8347'],
                   'code': ['Rc1', 'Rc1', 'Rc1', 'Rc1',  'Rc1'],
                   'desc': ['RANDOM CODE1', 'RANDOM CODE1', 'RANDOM CODE', 'RANDOM CODE', 'RANDOM CODE'],
                   'start date': ['123189', '123189', '123189', '123189',  '123189']
                   })
# df4 has 1 additional record for '8347' this should not show up on the results data
# For 'area id' record 8150 & 8260, 'desc' column value == RANDOM CODE1 this should return a non matched result
# df4 is missing record '8363' and instead has a record of '8110', the missing record should account for a whole row non match,
    # additional record '8110' should not show up in the validation as it wasnt explicity called out in the config file

df4 = pd.DataFrame({'area id': ['8150', '8260', '8363', '8110', '8347'],
                   'code': ['Rc1', 'Rc1', 'Rc1', 'Rc1',  'Rc1'],
                   'desc': ['RANDOM CODE1', 'RANDOM CODE1', 'RANDOM CODE', 'RANDOM CODE', 'RANDOM CODE'],
                   'start date': ['123189', '123189', '123189', '123189',  '123189']
                   })

dfc.index = dfc.iloc[:,:2]
df2.index = df2.iloc[:,:2]
df3.index = df3.iloc[:,:2]
df4.index = df4.iloc[:,:2]

dfc.mask(df3.isin(dfc),other='<Match>')

area id code    desc    start date
(8150, Rc1) <Match> <Match> RANDOM CODE <Match>
(8260, Rc1) <Match> <Match> RANDOM CODE <Match>
(8363, Rc1) <Match> <Match> <Match> <Match>
(8448, Rc1) <Match> <Match> <Match> <Match>

dfc.where(df3.isin(dfc), other=f'config:(config value) | export: (export value))')

    area id code    desc    start date
(8150, Rc1) 8150    Rc1 config:(config value) | export: (export value)) 123189
(8260, Rc1) 8260    Rc1 config:(config value) | export: (export value)) 123189
(8363, Rc1) 8363    Rc1 RANDOM CODE 123189
(8448, Rc1) 8448    Rc1 RANDOM CODE 123189


Welcome to SO! An expected output would also be great.

Did you say multi index? I'm not seeing any in your provided input. Not sure it's a sufficient [mre] for you.

thank you and sorry that i didnt clarify basically what i am looking for is to show the non matches as Config: RANDOM CODE | Export: RANDOM CODE1 in the non matched cell in the above example. in my main program that i am working with im reading from excel so it looks like this config = pd.read_excel('Test Docs\\Test_Config_2.xlsx', index_col=(0,1),engine='calamine').fillna("<BLank>") export = pd.read_excel('Test Docs\\Test_Export_2.xlsx', index_col=(0,1),engine='calamine').fillna("<BLank>") but in the example i gave i just passed the index through dfc.index = dfc.iloc[:,:2]

im sorry if i didnt format my response well. the reason i am doing the index that way is because the column names arent always static but my index values will always be the first 2 columns

also there are some values that are blank by default in the files im working with so i needed to fill them to get a correct match value. through doing some research with list comprehensions it seems like i may benefit from a generator object. my main issue is that i want it to run fast which is why im trying with mask. tbh i probably needed to just do more research but i promise ive been playing with the code for a few weeks and just wanted to see about getting some feedback from someone more knowledgeable

Here is how you would compare dfc with df3:
import pandas as pd

dfc = pd.DataFrame({
    'area id': ['8150', '8260', '8363', '8448'],
    'code': ['Rc1', 'Rc1', 'Rc1', 'Rc1'],
    'desc': ['RANDOM CODE', 'RANDOM CODE', 'RANDOM CODE', 'RANDOM CODE'],
    'start date': ['123189', '123189', '123189', '123189']
})

df3 = pd.DataFrame({
    'area id': ['8150', '8260', '8363', '8448', '8347'],
    'code': ['Rc1', 'Rc1', 'Rc1', 'Rc1', 'Rc1'],
    'desc': ['RANDOM CODE1', 'RANDOM CODE1', 'RANDOM CODE', 'RANDOM CODE', 'RANDOM CODE'],
    'start date': ['123189', '123189', '123189', '123189', '123189']
})

dfc.set_index(['area id', 'code'], inplace=True)
df3.set_index(['area id', 'code'], inplace=True)

df3 = df3.reindex_like(dfc)

def compare_dataframes(config, export):
    match_mask = config == export
    result = config.mask(~match_mask, other='<Match>')
    
    for col in config.columns:
        result[col] = result[col].where(
            match_mask[col], 
            other=f"config: {config[col]} | export: {export[col]}"
        )
        
    return result

result_df = compare_dataframes(dfc, df3)

print(result_df)

which gives
                                                           desc start date
area id code                                                              
8150    Rc1   config: area id  code\n8150     Rc1     RANDOM...     123189
8260    Rc1   config: area id  code\n8150     Rc1     RANDOM...     123189
8363    Rc1                                         RANDOM CODE     123189
8448    Rc1                                         RANDOM CODE     123189

Update: To get the mismatches:
import pandas as pd

dfc = pd.DataFrame({
    'area id': ['8150', '8260', '8363', '8448'],
    'code': ['Rc1', 'Rc1', 'Rc1', 'Rc1'],
    'desc': ['RANDOM CODE', 'RANDOM CODE', 'RANDOM CODE', 'RANDOM CODE'],
    'start date': ['123189', '123189', '123189', '123189']
})

df3 = pd.DataFrame({
    'area id': ['8150', '8260', '8363', '8448', '8347'],
    'code': ['Rc1', 'Rc1', 'Rc1', 'Rc1', 'Rc1'],
    'desc': ['RANDOM CODE1', 'RANDOM CODE1', 'RANDOM CODE', 'RANDOM CODE', 'RANDOM CODE'],
    'start date': ['123189', '123189', '123189', '123189', '123189']
})

dfc.set_index(['area id', 'code'], inplace=True)
df3.set_index(['area id', 'code'], inplace=True)

df3 = df3.reindex_like(dfc)

def compare_dataframes(config, export):
    match_mask = config == export
    result = config.mask(~match_mask, other='<Match>')
    
    mismatches = []
    
    for col in config.columns:
        mismatch_rows = ~match_mask[col]
        mismatch_indices = config.index[mismatch_rows]
        for idx in mismatch_indices:
            mismatch_info = {
                'area id': idx[0],
                'code': idx[1],
                'column': col,
                'config_value': config.at[idx, col],
                'export_value': export.at[idx, col]
            }
            mismatches.append(mismatch_info)
        
    return result, mismatches

result_df, mismatches = compare_dataframes(dfc, df3)

print(result_df)

for mismatch in mismatches:
    print(mismatch)

which gives
                     desc start date
area id code                        
8150    Rc1       <Match>     123189
8260    Rc1       <Match>     123189
8363    Rc1   RANDOM CODE     123189
8448    Rc1   RANDOM CODE     123189
{'area id': '8150', 'code': 'Rc1', 'column': 'desc', 'config_value': 'RANDOM CODE', 'export_value': 'RANDOM CODE1'}
{'area id': '8260', 'code': 'Rc1', 'column': 'desc', 'config_value': 'RANDOM CODE', 'export_value': 'RANDOM CODE1'}


Thank you for this!. i did remove the '~' which allowed me to see the matches displayed as 'Match' which is preferred. I was wondering if there is a way to only get the specific value from the corresponding unmatched value for the index item. In the example you provide im seeing all of the mismatched items in every non matched cell which can be a lot to look at when working with a big file. Is there a way to pull the individual values corresponding to the unmatched cell without slowing the program down significantly.

I have another prototype using apply() but it is slower than i would like on big files like 30k plus rows(btw im working with excel files). I like the speed of mask and it almost gets me where i need to be which is why i asked specifically about mask/where. if there is a better way then i would love to know, i am fairly new to programming and still researching topics

@BenjaminSoto-Roberts Updated my answer to get the mismatches as lists. Don't forget to mark the answer as accepted and upvote.

Thank you sir. I can def play with this, i dont have enough reputation to cast a vote but my feedback was recorded
